# Alternative locations for .cls files

Tags: documentclass

I have written some software which outputs `.tex` files and uses a custom `.cls` file. I have a makefile for this software but I don't know what to do with the `.cls` file.

Is `~/texmf/tex/latex/` the only location to store these files? I would prefer not to be creating directories in the users home directory. When I install other `.cls` files what location are they installed in? I can't find this information anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to TeX S! If you're under  TeX Live, it defines a `texlive/texmf-local/` directory, which is done for that.

Answer (score 1):

Put the files wherever you want and add the folder to the `TEXINPUTS` variable in your make file

```
export TEXINPUTS := .:/path/to/the/local/folder//:
```